# powershell parameter PolicyStore and Confirm

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

I am removing some IP addresses by using:

```
Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $my.InterfaceIndex.
```

Which works OK. But when I add the parameter `-Confirm`

```
Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $my.InterfaceIndex -Confirm $false.
```

It fails as follows:

```
Remove-NetIPAddress : No matching MSFT_NetIPAddress objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress 
class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetIPAddress  WHERE ((IPAddress LIKE 'False')) AND ((InterfaceIndex = 15)). Verify query 
parameters and retry.
At line:9 char:1
+ Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $my.InterfaceIndex -Confirm $false
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:String) [Remove-NetIPAddress], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Remove-NetIPAddress
```

How should I use the `-Confirm`, and `-PolicyStore` parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Because `-Confirm` is a Switch parameter you pass false to it with a colon:

```
Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $my.InterfaceIndex -Confirm:$false
```

You pass true to it by just declaring it on its own.

Comment: Hello Mark, do you know how to use -PolicyStore option? I encountered same problem.